# Who represent an ISA relationship in Relation Model?

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship, workbench

[image]

I have this example

In the Secretary, i need to create and id? Who represent in WorkBench?

Or i only need to create `1:n` relationship?

My model have:

```
Engineer : eng_type, fk: employee_ssn
```

Comment: What do you mean "Workbench"? SQL workbench? An ID is not part of your diagram. And there does not appear to be any `1:n` relations here unless an employee has multiple jobs

Comment: MySQL Workbench to create tables and relationship. Engineer is a specialization of employee, can you give me an answer what relationship i need to create?

Comment: Your diagram shows the relations. Why is `SSN` a `fk`? That should be the primary key, it looks like...  This really depends on how denormalized you want. You definitely need an `Employee` table, then that could have a foreign key to a `JobType` table. Not sure what to do about the "sub-types" of employee, though.

Comment: Well my teacher said that this is right but the relationshipp is wrong

Comment: And you didn't ask the teacher or other people in your class what is wrong? Without context its hard to know what you were asked to create.

Comment: The context is this, this is one Software Company that have employes, this employes can be IT or design

Comment: Okay... anyways, the largest problem you have at the moment is how to associate "Secretaries" to their "Typing speed". How is that any different than a "Technician" with a "Tgrade"? Perhaps you can combine those "sub-types", and just add one attribute to the "Employee". Making one table for each "job-type" seems like a bad model that doesn't scale for new "job-types"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diagram translates into the following tables:

```
Employee (Ssn PK, Fname, Minit, Lname, Birth_date, Address, Job_type)
Secretary (Ssn PK/FK, Job_type FK, Typing_speed)
Technician (Ssn PK/FK, Job_type FK, Tgrade)
Engineer (Ssn PK/FK, Job_type FK, Eng_type)
```

`Job_type` has a domain of `(Secretary, Technician, Engineer)`, an enum type would be suitable in MySQL. The FK constraints on the subtype tables are composite: `Secretary (Ssn, Job_type) REFERENCES Employee (Ssn, Job_type)`, and similarly for the other two subtypes. You'll need to create suitable indexes.

MySQL doesn't support check constraints, which would've been nice to enforce the `Job_type` of each subtype. You can create a trigger to do the same. With that in place, the composite FK constraints prevent an employee from having more than one subtype at any time - each record in the `Employee` table can have only one `Job_type`, and only the subtype table with the matching `Job_type` can have a matching record.

If you want `Employee` to participate totally in the subtype relationship (i.e. every employee must have a subtype), you could create a trigger for that too.

Comment: Hello, this is not the answer. The answer is that, because is one specialization, the son (node) gets the father (employee) id where hi is the   fk in the same time. This is the relationship that is 1:1 identify relationship, identify because we know what entity is.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding you. The Employee `Ssn` is your identifier, it is underlined and there is no ID field in the diagram. I indicated the Ssn as both PK and FK in the subtypes.

Comment: Well Ssn is the "id" that are using in the diagram.

Comment: In most cases, such as Associations 1: N and 1: 1 take a "non-identification" calls. An exception are like associations resulting from a ISA connection, which take a que a foreign key in Entity daughter IS ALSO a Primary Entity this key. WHEN creates An Entity daughter, THIS MUST be blank Built and First Thing to Do logo and create a link 1: n identification between an entity daughter and Entity parent to obtain, as first attribute (inherited), a Primary Key Table father, What Becomes Primary Also key in the child while being foreign.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're saying.